# Cannot load Google Images from its API using jQuery getJSON

Tags: api, jquery, getjson

My code is below:

```
$.getJSON('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=Google&v=1.0', 
function(json) {
  alert(json);
})​
```

You can try this code here: http://jsbin.com/ofaru3/edit

The ajax is error

imagesFailed to load resource

How cna I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Google Images Search API document:
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html#json_reference

Answer (score 6):

You need `&callback=?` on the URL there to trigger JSONP, like this:

```
$.getJSON('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=Google&v=1.0&callback=?', 
function(json) {
  alert(json);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eunAc/).  Without the `&callback?` it's trying to fetch the data from a remote domain with an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) and failing/being blocked due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  This is exactly the type of situation [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) is for.

From the [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) docs:

> **JSONP**
>   If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the `jsonp` data type in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) for more details.